Which integers can be expressed as $P(t)^2 + Q(t)^2 + R(t)^5$?
Inspired by this article and that one, I have two questions:
(1) Is the question of whether every integer can be expressed in the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^5$ ($x$, $y$, $z$ in $\mathbb{Z}$) an open problem?
(2) Which integers can be expressed in the form $P(t)^2 + Q(t)^2 + R(t)^5$, where $P(t)$, $Q(t)$, and $R(t)$ are non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients?
With the help of some of the participants in this discussion on MSE, we succeeded in proving that the following integers satisfy (2) :
$A=a^2+b^2$ (where $a$ and $b$ are non-zero integers) , $0$, $1$ , $2^2$ , $2^2\times3^4$ , $2^2\times3\times11^5$ , $2^2\times11^5\times19$ , $-7$ , $-2^3\times3$ , $-2^4\times3^5$ , and those obtained by multiplying them by $k^5$, where $k=m^2+n^2$ (where $m$ and $n$ are integers).
Here are the identities that prove it, some obtained by trial and error and with the help of a computer:
$$(A^2at^5+b)^2+(A^2bt^5-a)^2-(At^2)^5=A$$
$$(4t^5)^2+(4t^5)^2+(-2t^2)^5=0$$
$$(2t^4-2t^2+1)^2+(t^5-2t^3+2t)^2+(-t^2)^5=1$$
$$(50t^5+25t^4+10t^2-10t-1)^2+(25t^5-50t^4-20t^2-5t+2)^2-(5t^2+1)^5=4=2^2$$
$$(3t^4-18t^2+9)^2+(t^5-12t^3+27t)^2-(t^2-3)^5=324=2^2\times3^4$$
$$(50t^5+125t^4-800t^3-790t^2+1990t+619)^2+(25t^5-250t^4-400t^3+1580t^2+995t-1238)^2-(5t^2-7)^5=1932612=2^2\times3\times11^5$$
$$(7t^4+158t^2-3499)^2+(t^5-12t^3-1053t)-(t^2+5)^5=12239876=2^2\times11^5\times19$$
$$(2t^4+38t^2+181)^2+(t^5+18t^3+82t)^2-(t^2+8)^5=-7$$
$$(4t^5 + 4t^4 + 8t^3 + 4t^2 + 8t + 2)^2+(-4t^5 + 4t^4 - 8t^3 + 4t^2 - 8t + 2)^2-(2t^2 + 2)^5=-24=-2^3\times3$$
$$(50t^5+200t^3+40t^2+240t+76)^2+(25t^5+100t^3-80t^2+120t-152)^2-(5t^2+8)^5=-3888=-2^4\times3^5$$
But there are surely others, aren't there? Is there a way to get them all? Conversely, is it possible to prove that some values are not solutions of (2), perhaps like $-1$ or $3$?

Representation of -1 would imply that equation x^2+y^2=x^5-1 has infinitely many integer solutions. But this is an open problem, see Table 14 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.08518

Sorry for the rather random question, but is there here possibly some (deeper) relation with the fact that $x^2 + y^2 + z^5 = 0$ happens to represent the $A_4$ du Val singularity? Or maybe it's just a coincidence.

Question 1 is a known open question. In  a 2017 paper of mine, part (i) of Conjecture 5.1 is as follows: If $q$ is an odd prime or a product of some primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then each integer $m$ can be written as $x^2+y^2-z^q$ with $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z^+$ in infinitely many ways. See also Theorem 5.1 in that paper and the comments in A266277 at OEIS
and A266314 at OEIS.
